# The connotations of 'You tell!'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Dialogue:

Dwight: Oh hey, I've been to the amusement park that you referred to me last week. It was amazing!

Jim: You tell!

What does the response 'You tell!' means? The connotations of course.

Comment: Where did you find this conversation?  Are you sure it is correctly transcribed?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, is something wrong with the transcription?

Comment: I am not familiar with the collocation *You tell!* for one thing,  and **referred to me** also seemed questionable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the context of you example conversation

> You tell!

would  mean

> Tell me all about it!
>   Good for you!

A BrE speaker might use

> Do tell!

Comment: 'Tell me all about it!' fits well. Mostly I've heard it in sitcoms.